# Propagate ENV variables to ZSH

Tags: bash, zsh

I'm calling a script using:

```
zsh -c 'myscript' -- $args
```

where myscript exists in a folder that is added to my PATH by `.zshrc`. When I run that command zsh can't find the myscript, since the PATH is reset to the default.

When I run a similar command using bash:

```
bash -c 'myscript' -- $args
```

the `myscript` is found, I'm assuming since the PATH is passed through to bash.

Is there any way to enforce the PATH, and all other ENV vars, to propagate down to zsh?

Comment: The difference is not how `bash` and `zsh` inherit `PATH` from their parent (which is identical), but in how your `.bashrc` and `.zshrc` modify `PATH`.

Comment: It seems that I can not reproduce the issue. If I put `myscript` in `$HOME/foo` and add this to `PATH` (`PATH=$HOME/foo:$PATH`) on the current shell, then any subsequent calls to `zsh -c 'myscript'` are successful. So zsh seems to inherit the environment correctly. Is there any place in your zsh configuration where PATH is set to a fixed value, e.g. `PATH=/somedir/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` instead of `PATH=/somedir/bin:$PATH`? Also `~/.zshrc` is usually *not* read when starting a non-interactive zsh session, so you may need to check `~/.zshenv` and `/etc/zshenv`.